# how to query based on pfobject/pfuser associated with another pfobject in parse.com?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a Parse class called FriendRelation.  This class has two users, one a friend the other a user.

I want to get all of the messages posted by all of the friends of a user. I am attempting to do so with the following query:

```
 PFQuery *innerQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRelation"];
            [innerQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:currentUser];
            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
            [query whereKey:@"userMessage" matchesQuery:innerQuery];
            [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {

           }];
```

This query comes back with no results.

I believe this is occurring because of the line:

```
 [query whereKey:@"userMessage" matchesQuery:innerQuery];
```

The where key needs to be a FriendRelation to match.  Is this correct?

How can I make the results of the inner query be a user that will intern match the matching query?

Thanks!

Comment: The second line of code is calling a method of the `query` instance, however, the `query` instance is not declared until the third line of code. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: that was a typo, I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using

`- (void)whereKey:(NSString *)key matchesKey:(NSString *)otherKey inQuery:(PFQuery *)query`

Something like:

```
PFQuery *innerQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRelation"];
        [innerQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:currentUser];
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
        [query whereKey:@"userMessage" matchesKey:@"firendUser" inQuery:innerQuery];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
            //do something useful..
       }];
```

Let me know how it goes!